# Creating a Google Cloud Data Fusion instance does not create the service account

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I have created a Google Cloud Data Fusion instance, and per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/create-instance) I am searching for the service account listed to add the additional role. However, this service account is nowhere to be found in the IAM of the project. Am I expected to create the service account or this should be done as part of creating the instance?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service account is created in the [`tenant project`](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/concepts/architecture#tenant_project) associated to your Data Fusion instance (that's why the email suffix should be a random identifier + '-tp'). Therefore, you can't see it in your project but you can add the desired permissions in the `IAM` tab.